# Online service for crowdsource text labbling

Tags: classification, data-mining, labels

I'm trying to make a text classificator for short texts. 
For that task, I need a labeled samples dataset. I already have samples but most of them are not labeled. I'm tired to label them in excel alone =)

I wonder if there are any free/open source services for crowdsource text labeling so I can ask my friends to help me.
Are there any services for that?

Comment: https://gengo.ai/datasets/the-best-25-datasets-for-natural-language-processing/?utm_campaign=c&utm_medium=quora&utm_source=community